# Concatenate passed variable to name of form element

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a form with elements 'textbox1' thru to 'textbox10'. I am trying to use a javascript function to pass the returned row ID from an SQL database for example:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="" onclick="javascript:functionname(<?= $sql_rowid ?>)" />
```

I want to be able to concatenate the passed row ID to a form element name. This is incorrect of course, but it may give an insight into what I am attempting to do:

document.form_name.textbox + passedSQLRowID.value

Therefore, I am able to access the value of 'textbox1'...

Any ideas?

Prabhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following notation:

```
document.form_name["textbox" + passedSQLRowID].value
```

Comment: Yep, 9 years later this saved me 2 hours.